# How to iterate through a bash array while removing an element?

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

**GNU bash**, version 4.3.42(1)-release (arm-openwrt-linux-gnu)

I'm trying to script an iptables rule using a bash array.

$NETID is used to create network addresses. For example, 192.168.**10**.0/24, 192.168.**20**.0/24, etc.

I'm trying to create a temporary variable ($NETID_TMP) where the "i" in ${NETID[@]} is **removed** from $NETID_TMP. For example, if "i" = 10, NETID_TMP=(20 30 40).

**Script:**

```
    #!/opt/bin/bash
    NETID=(10 20 30 40)
    for (( i=0; i<${#NETID[@]}; i++ )); do
       NETID_TMP=(${NETID[*]})
       unset NETID_TMP[${NETID[i]}]
       iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.${NETID[i]}.0/24 -d 192.168.${NETID_TMP[0]}.0/24,192.168.${NETID_TMP[1]}.0/24,192.168.${NETID_TMP[2]}.0/24 -j DROP
    done
```

The result should be ...

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d 192.168.20.0/24,192.168.30.0/24,192.168.40.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.20.0/24 -d 192.168.10.0/24,192.168.30.0/24,192.168.40.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.30.0/24 -d 192.168.10.0/24,192.168.20.0/24,192.168.40.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.40.0/24 -d 192.168.10.0/24,192.168.20.0/24,192.168.30.0/24 -j DROP
```

Comment: Which element do you want to remove from the array? Your question title and content doesn't seem to go well with each other? Could you please explain or rephrase?

Comment: K. Which element from the NETID array that you want to remove? All I can see is, elements are present in different IPs that you've mentioned.

Comment: Now I see, you want to iteratively remove elements and inject them in appropriate place? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. $NETID will always equal (10 20 30 40). $NETID_TMP is based on $NETID, but has the "i" element removed (i.e., "10"). When the for loop iterates, the "i" element will move to the second element (20) and $NETID_TMP would consist of $NETID minus the second element (i.e., "10 30 40".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
netid=(10 20 30 40)

for i in "${netid[@]}"; do
    out="iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.$i.0/24 -d "

    for j in "${netid[@]}"; do
        (( i == j )) && continue
        out+="192.168.$j.0/24,"
    done
    out="${out%,} -j DROP"

    printf '%s\n' "$out"
done
```

This Bash script produces

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d 192.168.20.0/24,192.168.30.0/24,192.168.40.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.20.0/24 -d 192.168.10.0/24,192.168.30.0/24,192.168.40.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.30.0/24 -d 192.168.10.0/24,192.168.20.0/24,192.168.40.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.40.0/24 -d 192.168.10.0/24,192.168.20.0/24,192.168.30.0/24 -j DROP
```

through a double loop.  The inner loop skips the iterations where the loop variable is numerically equal to the loop variable of the outer loop to create the desired effect.

Once you have the string in `$out`, you may `eval` it.

Alternatively, to avoid `eval`:

```
netid=(10 20 30 40)

for i in "${netid[@]}"; do
    sarg="192.168.$i.0/24"
    darg=""

    for j in "${netid[@]}"; do
        (( i == j )) && continue
        darg+="192.168.$j.0/24,"
    done
    darg="${darg%,}"

    iptables -I FORWARD -s "$sarg" -d "$darg" -j DROP
done
```

The variable substitution `${parameter%word}` will remove `word` from the very end of `$parameter`, so `darg="${darg%,}"` will remove the comma at the end af `$darg`.

---

Update after question in comment:

The only thing `bash`-specific about the above is the use of the array `$netid`, the `+=` operator to append to the `$darg` string and `((...))`.  We may turn this into a `sh` script like this (here assuming `$IFS` still has its default value):

```
netid="10 20 30 40"

for i in $netid; do
    sarg="192.168.$i.0/24"
    darg=""

    for j in $netid; do
        [ "$i" -eq "$j" ] && continue
        darg="${darg}192.168.$j.0/24,"
    done
    darg="${darg%,}"

    iptables -I FORWARD -s "$sarg" -d "$darg" -j DROP
done
```

If you have a separate list of numbers that you'd like to plug in for `$darg`, use that in the inner loop in place of `$netid`.  It should be a string of space-separated numbers.

Comment: excellent!! ^_^. You're so fast, when I got the concept, you produced the result. Great :D

Comment: @kusalananda - Does "(( i == j )) && continue" mean if "i" = "j" to skip the next command and return to the "for j in ..." line ?

Comment: @uihdff Yes, exactly. It corresponds to `next` in Perl. It continues with the next iteration of the current loop.

Comment: @Kusalananda - How could you write this in sh instead of bash if the value for $darg came from a variable called $DST_ID ?

Comment: @uihdff See updated answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda - How could you iterate $darg if it its values came from a second shell variable called $DST_ID ? For example, "for j in $DST_ID; do" ?

Comment: @uihdff Yes, and if any number in `$DST_ID` is equal to the current number `$i`, then that number will be skipped.

Comment: @Kusalananda - I have to move this to another question as a moderator might flag it as having nothing to do with bash. While the array example worked perfectly, I later found out that by the time the script ran, bash as an Entware package, had not loaded yet. Can you follow this to this new question ? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390283

Comment: @Kusalananda - In the updated "sh" example, how would you write the script to output one value for $darg at a time ?

Answer (score 2):

It's easier with `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
nets=(192.168.{10,20,30,40}.0/24)
for net ($nets) iptables -I FORWARD -s $net -d ${(j:,:)nets:#$net} -j DROP
```