# How to iterate two variables in a sh script?

Tags: shell-script, shell

Using kernel 2.6.x

How would you script the result below with the following variables using sh (not bash, zsh, etc.) ?

```
VAR1="abc def ghi"
VAR2="1 2 3"
CONFIG="$1"

for i in $VAR1; do
   for j in $VAR2; do
      [ "$i" -eq "$j" ] && continue
   done
command $VAR1 $VAR2
done
```

**Desired result:**

```
command abc 1
command def 2
command ghi 3
```

Comment: See also: [how can we use multiple variables in single for loop in shell script?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/279760)

Comment: Or: [How to iterate a command with two different variables?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/386507) (that one being an answer to another question of yours!)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I had started this discussion on that question. But since bash couldn't be used, I expected a moderator to flag and close the question. That's why a new question without bash was created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
#! /bin/sh

VAR1="abc def ghi"
VAR2="1 2 3"

fun()
{
    set $VAR2
    for i in $VAR1; do
        echo command "$i" "$1"
        shift
    done
}

fun
```

Output:

```
command abc 1
command def 2
command ghi 3
```

Comment: You beat me too it by a few seconds, although I did not have it in a function to protect the positional parameters. Neat.

Comment: Does sh support the shift command ?

Comment: @uihdff `sh` supports both functions and `shift`.

Comment: @uihdff You can just leave out the enclosing `fun() { ... }`.  But then `set $VAR2` overrides script parameters `$1, $2, ...`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! You are the man ... by a few seconds !

Comment: If a third variable was to be used ($VAR3), do you add "set $VAR3" after "set $VAR2" and then refer to it as $2 ? For example if a second command to be run was ... echo command "$i" "$2".

Comment: No.  If a third value is to be used than you install a better shell and use arrays.  Or you write a wrapper script.

Answer (score 7):

A variation on [Satō Katsura's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390289/116858) (here, a self-contained function):

```
func () {
    var=$1
    set -- $2

    for arg1 in $var; do
        printf 'command %s %s\n' "$arg1" "$1" # or  cmd "$arg1" "$1" directly
        shift
    done
}

func "abc def ghi" "1 2 3"
```

---

The following would work, but would overwrite the positional parameters of the script that it is in:

```
var1="abc def ghi"
var2="1 2 3"

set -- $var2
for arg1 in $var1; do
    printf 'command %s %s\n' "$arg1" "$1"
    shift
done
```

Comment: Had to add the "CONFIG="$1" variable as I found out this script takes an argument for a file path. How does this change the script ?

Comment: @uihdff As long as all references to `$1` happens _above_ the non-function solution (like saving `$1` in a variable with e.g. `CONFIG=$1`), it should be ok.

Comment: @uihdff More importantly, _before `set -- $var2`_.

Comment: If, on the command line, you have "test.sh /etc/test2.sh" where CONFIG=$1 refers to test2.sh, there should be no problem ?

Comment: @uihdff I wouldn't think so, no. You can always run the script with `sh -x ./test.sh /etc/test2.sh` to see what actually happens.

Comment: What do you mean by the non-function version overwriting the positional parameters ?

Comment: @uihdff If you put that code in a script, and if that script takes any command line arguments.  Then these command line arguments would be replaced by the `set` call. `set -- $var2` would overwrite any existing positional parameters, `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc.

Comment: So the only way to to protect the positional parameters is to wrap the code in a function ? When this script runs, the OS sets another file as a command line argument, hence CONFIG="$1".

Comment: @uihdff Or, you may save the positional parameters in variables, as you're doing, yes.

Comment: Do you mean a new variable like $CONFIG_TMP could be set equal to the contents of $CONFIG, the function removed, allow the positional parameters to be overwritten and then reset $CONFIG to be equal to $CONFIG_TMP ?

Comment: @uihdff I mean that as long as you save the values of the positional parameters that you need to keep hold of, like what you're doing in the code in the question, it's fine. I wrote the "warning" in the answer in case someone else picks the code up and runs with it without properly studying the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Following is one of the solution.

```
#!/bin/sh
var1="a b c"
var2="1 2 3"
set -- $var2
for i in $var1
do
    echo $i $1
    shift
done
```