# Loop through variable in bash using "2" variables

Tags: bash, shell-script

So I know how to loop through 1 variable:

```
folder="(first|second|third)"
for i in "${folder[@]}"; do
  rclone move /mounts/$folder/cache
done
```

But how to do it when they are 2?

```
folder="(first|second|third)"
mount="(something1|something2|something3)"
for i in "${folder[@]}"; do
  rclone move /mounts/$folder/cache $mount
done
```

So script should loop each folder with correct mount added.

At the end, execution should be like this:

```
 rclone move /mounts/first/cache something1
 rclone move /mounts/second/cache something2
 rclone move /mounts/third/cache something3
```

Comment: [How to iterate two variables in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390283/how-to-iterate-two-variables-in-a-sh-script)

Comment: Done. Final version added of explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to iterate over the array *index* number and not the value.  This is done using the `${!folder[@]}` syntax.

In that way you can access both arrays via the same index inside the loop

e.g.  (putting `echo` in front for this example)

```
folder=(first second third)
mount=(something1 something2 something3)
for i in "${!folder[@]}"; do
  echo rclone move /mounts/${folder[$i]}/cache ${mount[$i]}
done
```

Will output

```
rclone move /mounts/first/cache something1
rclone move /mounts/second/cache something2
rclone move /mounts/third/cache something3
```